# Determine dynamic file name in Windows batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, zip, 7zip

We have a single file in a fixed directory that will have the name `database-x.x.x.zip` where `x.x.x` is a version number that can change.

We want to create a batch script that will unzip this file - we can use 7zip to unzip the file from a batch script but we need to be able to pass the file name to 7zip - how can we determine the file name in a batch script given that the file name will not be constant?

The script needs to unzip an archive and then run an ant file which was in the archive:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\CommandLine\7za.exe" x %FILE%
ant -f %UNZIPPED_ARCHIVE_DIR%\db.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

use the fantastic for loop

from the command line

```
for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('dir database-?.?.?.?.zip /b') do 7za xxx %f
```

from the batch file

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir database-?.?.?.?.zip /b') do 7za xxx %%f
```

where xxx is the options passes to 7zip

Comment: Perhaps one two many question marks are there and ? only matches a single character (version numbers could easily be multiple digit)

Answer (score 0):

**Source:** `extract.bat`:

```
@echo off
::: extract.bat - Extract all database-*.zip files in the given folder
::: usage: extract.bat [folder]
:::     folder - Search for files here (defaults to current folder)

set search=database-*.zip /b
if "%~1" neq "" set search=%1\%search%

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir %search%') do (
  7z x %%f %%~nf
  ant -f %%~nf\db.xml
)
```

If you really need to exclude database zips that don't follow the version folder format (eg if there's one called `database-old.zip` and that shouldn't be extracted) then you'll need to find a regex matcher for the command line in Windows - which is possible.  That -or- if you keep your version numbers down to a single digit, then you can use the `?` single character match.

You may also want to add some checking (before `7z...` line) to make sure he folder doesn't already exist and do something if it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
powershell Expand-Archive x.x.x.zip "where_you_want_to_unzip"
```

if you NEED to use 7zip to unzip then I cant help you as for unzipping via batch files I always just use this.